# How to create a task flow after scenario?

Tags: information-architecture, user-centered-design, wireframe, task-flow

I am trying to create a user experience design for ATM users. These users are semi-literate. I have created a Design strategy, Persona and Scenario. My next step is to create a Task flow and then wireframes. How do I create a task flow which matches the user's mental model?

Comment: Empathize. Put yourself in the users shoes and try to come up with the steps. Tell us more about waht you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question, but I will help guide you to an answer by providing some articles.

The first, is from [UX Pin here](https://studio.uxpin.com/blog/creating-perfect-user-flows-for-smooth-ux/). It's a decent overview on how to create user flows.

Next, you need a tool to create these flows and wireframes. You can sketch with pen and paper, use illustrator, omnigraffle, keynote, sketch, etc to create these flows and wireframes. Whatever works best for you. The goal here is not to learn a new piece of software but to use the tool you're most comfortable with so you can move fast and make mistakes/revisions.

I use Sketch. So here is a good article on [how to produce flows in Sketch](https://medium.com/@wixelhq/streamlining-the-design-process-user-flow-to-final-design-using-sketch-ba71d2355bf9#.nb71orsy9). This is centered around web design, but you can imagine how this would work for an ATM. You may need to build your own wireframe template.

How this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I let me begin this by correcting this part “you construct a task-flow from the persona(s) in which you have already created.”

Mental-models are what thoughts people form around an idea or activity and these vary from person to person. These information “Mental-models" are incorporated into a persona.

To make this ease, you have already conducted a proper research, you learned about your target-audience you have analyzed the data that you gathered. You have interviewed your user to learn all about their motivation, behavioral, technology expertise, personality, etc. Then the use-scenario was created. You may or may not have created an information architecture based on the title, I would say it’s a big project and there are so many information that you have gathered that needed to be structured. Before undertaking conceptual and perceptual (visual) designs of your application, you may need to prepare the information architecture.

How to create a task-flow from persona?

1. Which users/personas you will be designing your flows for
2. What user and business objectives need to be accomplished
3. Prepare Application Map: The application map provides an overall
   snapshot of the structure and navigation of the app. It served as a
   reference point while creating various task flows and wireframes
4. You start with the building blocks – e.g. where this logo goes or
   where those content would be moved to. Start with few easy flow like
   “Onboarding Task-Flow” example “user lands on the system -> welcome
   screen displayed -> etc. Below is an example of task-flow :

[image]

Good Sites to provide you with more information:

1. [Information Architecture](http://bitstrategist.com/work/information-architecture/)
2. [Stop Designing pages and start designing flows](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/stop-designing-pages-start-designing-flows/)
3. [Build it with the user in mind: how to design user-flow](http://conversionxl.com/how-to-design-user-flow/)

Hope these information help you :). Thank you.